# Deleting .png File through ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, listview

I am making an application for personal use that will organize .png files and will let me remotely delete them from the directory through the application (through a ListView).

I have a snippet that will delete the file from the ListView, but not from the actual file directory. I want to be able to do both when I click delete.

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("This will delete the file from the folder. Are you sure?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            for (int i = fileDisplayListView.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ListViewItem item = fileDisplayListView.SelectedItems[i];
                fileDisplayListView.Items[item.Index].Remove();
                File.Delete(fbd.SelectedPath + fileDisplayListView.Items.ToString());
            }
    }
```

Additional snippet for more information..

```
private void openToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        fbd.ShowDialog();
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fbd.SelectedPath);
        directoryPath.Text = "Directory: " + fbd.SelectedPath;
        FileInfo[] Files =
            di.GetFiles("*.PNG*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        if (Files.Length == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("No .png files found in directory...", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        fileDisplayListView.Items.Clear();
        foreach (FileInfo f in Files)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(f.Name);             
           this.fileDisplayListView.Items.Add(f.Name);            
        }
        this.fileDisplayListView.View = View.Details;
        this.fileDisplayListView.Refresh();
    }
```

The last part of it, `File.Delete(fbd.SelectedPath + fileDisplayListView.Items.ToString());`
is not functional. Please help!

Comment: I'm guesing that instead of `File.Delete(fbd.SelectedPath + fileDisplayListView.Items.ToString());` you should have `File.Delete(Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath, item.Text));`

Comment: using the Debugger can work wonders. are you capturing the selected File and it's FilePath..?

Comment: @Kedrzu I have tried this and it does not work. MethodMan I have put MessageBox() checkers between the final strings and the file path seems accurate. This seems like a very simple solution but it keeps outputting `FILE_DIRECTORYSystem.Windows.Forms.ListView+ListViewItemCollection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gets a list of all .jpg files in the directory, adds them to the ListView. By pressing the button it deletes the selected ListView elements and files:

```
private FileInfo[] files;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\User\Pictures").GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        var curentItem = listView1.SelectedItems[i];
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            if (curentItem.Text == file.Name)
            {
                listView1.Items.Remove(curentItem);
                file.Delete();
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I came up with a similar solution but this is functional so I will mark it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You really shouldn't automatically delete the row from the ListView. There are *many* things that could prevent the `Delete()` call from actually working. Better to refresh the control with the contents of the folder, after the delete.

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet I used to fix the application. It is a lot more directly related to how I am approaching the problem.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("This will delete the file from the folder. Are you sure?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            for (int i = fileDisplayListView.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ListViewItem item = fileDisplayListView.SelectedItems[i];
                string fpath = string.Empty;
                fileDisplayListView.Items[item.Index].Remove();
                fpath = fbd.SelectedPath.ToString() + "\\" + item.Text;
                File.Delete(fpath);
            }
```